# Why can't I get jQuery's live() or load() to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, live

Why does only the third method work?

```
$('#jqtest').live('load', function() {$(this).html('hi');}); //1

$('#jqtest').load(function() {$(this).html('hi');}); //2

$(window).load(function() {$('#jqtest').html('hi');}); //3


 <div id="jqtest">kldjfglkj</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `load()` function on arbitrary selectors; you can only use it on "any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object" ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)). `div`s don't have an associated URL, so neither of your first two techniques will bind a handler. `window` does have a URL, so it will call the handler.

You might also also be interested in [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the HTML "hi" to the element "#jqtest" when the document or window has loaded you're almost there.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#jqtest").html('hi');

});
```

This will change the value of "#jqtest" when the document has been loaded. You can also specify other events within the ready() function to only be executed once the page has fully loaded.