# Using jQuery Plugins with live()

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page that dynamically loads content with the jQuery load() function, so I need to use live() for each of my jQuery functions on this page. However, I am unable to get live() to work with jQuery plugins. For example, I want to use jQuery accordion:

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

But I cannot find the right syntax to get accordion to work with live(). I have tried:

```
$("#accordion").live("load", accordion());
$("#accordion").live("load", $("#accordion").accordion());
$("#accordion").live("load", $(this).accordion());
```

I either receive the "b is undefined" error, or "accordion is not defined."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use anonymous function

```
$("#accordion").live('load',function(){
    $(this).accordion();
});
```

**Edit:**

If the accordion is already in the page when you first render it, then you shouldn't call it using live(), but by page load

```
$(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think there is a problem with the "load" event. When the page loads it does not show the accordion. But when I change "load" to "click" and click the div it shows the accordion. Any idea how I can get the accordion to show on page load with live()?

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: same for me. with "load" it doesn't work, but with "click" it works.  any other hint? I need this to happen without user interaction.

Comment: "load" is not supported for live() or on() functions.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687287/why-cant-i-get-jquerys-live-or-load-to-work) could partly answer your question:

I would suggest using livequery instead to do this:

```
$("#accordion").livequery(
  function() { $(this).accordion(); }, 
  function() { $(this).accordion("destroy"); }
);
```

The first function will initialize jQuery UI's accordion functionality on any $("#accordion") element that's added to the DOM, and the second one will destroy the accordion object when that same element is removed from the DOM.